# Multiple internet routing SSL to same windows server

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2016, apache2

I need to allow both Exchange (2016) traffic and (Apache) SSL web traffic to the same server (Windows 2016). Both require a port forward on 443.

I have two incoming internet connections, both ADSL. eg 100.100.100.1 and 100.100.100.2. I can combine this into one router/modem so they end up being routed from the same device with a local address of 192.168.1.1.

My proposed solution is to set the NIC in the server to have 2 IP addresses, 192.168.1.10 and 192.168.1.11. Then I can route port 443 traffic on each incoming internet connection to a different address.

100.100.100.1:443 > 192.168.1.10:443
100.100.100.2:443 > 192.168.1.11:443

Then I can bind the exchange traffic to the 192.168.1.10 NIC address and the web traffic to 192.168.1.11 NIC address.

Both addresses will have their gateway set as the 192.168.1.1 address.

Will this work correctly? Or should it be configured differently?

And will there be any other problems with having the addresses set like that?

Comment: Do you need the two external IPs for load balancing or sth? Why not just use one IP? Your solution should work though.

Comment: Load balancing, considering the slow speed of the connections we wanted to move all web traffic to it's own connection.

Answer (score 1):

The setup you suggest may well work but to be honest I find it complex and probably hard to maintain over time.

I would suggest you consider fixing this at layer 7, i.e. forward all port 443 traffic to the server no matter what the IP, and use a reverse proxy on the server (Nginx or Apache or IIS with the right configs) to split incoming requests between Exchange and Apache depending on the domain and path in the request. You would then need to have the backend services listen on a different port so they can be differentiated locally on the server.

Comment: I have looked into changing the port for Exchange and this has been discussed as impossible (it would have been the easier solution). If I change web to port 444 (which is possible), does that impact the https on the web site at all? I also do need to ensure that the web traffic does exit out on the correct ADSL connection as well, since it's dedicated to offload the traffic.

Comment: You don't need to change the port, just the binding domain name. IIS can host ARR and a few websites simultanously.